# How to exclude boost, ace, stl when using oprofile?

Tags: c++, boost, oprofile

When I use oprofile tool for performance analysis, the result include many stats of stl function, ACE function and boost function, how can i exclude these libraries when use oprofile for statistics?

This is my result:

```
samples  cum. samples  %        cum. %     symbol name
13935    13935         15.8646  15.8646    std::less<unsigned int>::operator()(unsigned int const&, unsigned int const&) const
5552     19487          6.3208  22.1854    cache_result::decode(void*, unsigned long&, void const*, unsigned long)
5360     24847          6.1022  28.2876    cache::CWebCachePolicy::makexmlReply(cache::CCacheQueuedRequest*, iovec&, ACE_5_6_1::ACE_Message_Block*)
4661     29508          5.3064  33.5940    std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::_Identity<unsigned int>, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_S_key(std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned int> const*)
4649     34157          5.2928  38.8868    cache::CWebCachePolicy::updateOneSummaryResult(cache::CCacheQueuedRequest*, char*, int, int&, int*, int*, int*, char (*) [20], int*, int, int)
4568     38725          5.2005  44.0873    std::_Identity<unsigned int>::operator()(unsigned int const&) const
4266     42991          4.8567  48.9441    std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<unsigned int>::_Rb_tree_const_iterator(std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned int> const*)
3843     46834          4.3751  53.3192    std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::_Identity<unsigned int>, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::_S_value(std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned int> const*)
3000     49834          3.4154  56.7346    std::_Rb_tree<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::_Identity<unsigned int>, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<unsigned int> >::end() const
```

The result above shows many stl functions, which I want to do is just take care of my own function, not the standard libraries.

Comment: That would be rather difficult [because oprofile/perf doesn't know which parts are your code and what parts are from a librarby when sampling "where in the code is this"] (and most of the time annoying, since the time spent in library-code is a sign that you perhaps need to "do something different with your usage of STL")

Comment: Thanks. Is there another tool can achieve my goal?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.